# Where can I find documentation or paper mentioning pre-trained distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens model?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, bert, transformer, embeddings

I am trying to find more information about pre-trained model `distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens`. Can someone please point me to it's paper or documentation? Is it based on [DistilBERT, a distilled version of BERT: smaller, faster, cheaper and lighter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.01108) paper? This is published in March 2020. I am looking for links between this paper and Sentence-BERT ([sentence-transformers](https://www.sbert.net/index.html)). Original [sentence-bert](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.10084.pdf) paper is published in Aug 2019. I wanted to try pre-trained model using S-BERT model and hence tried `distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens` [model](https://www.sbert.net/examples/training/sts/README.html). After implementation I found out that it's much faster than other pre-trained models available on sentence-transformer [website](https://www.sbert.net/examples/training/sts/README.html). While studying it's paper I realised original paper do not mention this pre-trained model.

I found [Making Monolingual Sentence Embeddings Multilingual using
Knowledge Distillation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.09813.pdf) this paper published by same author which do mention `DistilmBERT` but not `DistilBert` Can someone please help me solve this mystery?

Answer (score 0):

The `distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens` model is the DistilBERT base model for natural language inference (NLI) using the MEAN pooling strategy for CLS tokens. For more information on the DistilBERT base model, have a look at [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.01108). The pooling strategy is simply the way the model combines the different embeddings (and thus information) from the different layers.